# Assessing values ​to a pandas column with conditions depending on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['paris', 'paris', 'nantes', 'berlin', 'berlin', 'berlin', 'tokyo'],
                        'id_res': [12, 12, 14, 28, 8, 4, 89]})


     col  id_res
0   paris      12
1   paris      12
2  nantes      14
3  berlin      28
4  berlin       8
5  berlin       4
6   tokyo      89
```

I want to create a "check" column whose values ​​are as follows:

- If a value in "col" has a duplicate and these duplicates have the same id_res, the value of "check" is False for duplicates
- If a value in "col" has duplicates and the "id_res" of these duplicates are different, assign True in "check" for the largest "id_res" value and False for the smallest
- If a value in "col" has no duplicates, the value of "check" is False.

The output I want is therefore:

```
    col  id_res  check
0   paris      12  False
1   paris      12  False
2  nantes      14  False
3  berlin      28   True
4  berlin       8  False
5  berlin       4  False
6   tokyo      89  False
```

I tried with groupby but no satisfactory result.
Can anyone help me plz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have 3 conditions, so use masks and take the logical intersection (AND/`&`):

```py
g = df_test.groupby('col')['id_res']

# is col duplicated?
m1 = df_test['col'].duplicated(keep=False)
# [ True  True False  True  True  True False]

# is id_res max of its group?
m2 = df_test['id_res'].eq(g.transform('max'))
# [ True  True  True  True False False  True]

# is group diverse? (more than 1 id_res)
m3 = g.transform('nunique').gt(1)
# [False False False  True  True  True False]

# check if all conditions True
df_test['check'] = m1&m2&m3
```

Output:

```
      col  id_res  check
0   paris      12  False
1   paris      12  False
2  nantes      14  False
3  berlin      28   True
4  berlin       8  False
5  berlin       4  False
6   tokyo      89  False
```

Answer (score 7):

Create 2 boolean masks then combine them and find the highest `id_res` value per `col`:

```py
m1 = df['col'].duplicated(keep=False)
m2 = ~df['id_res'].duplicated(keep=False)
df['check'] = df.index.isin(df[m1 & m2].groupby('col')['id_res'].idxmax())
print(df)

# Output
      col  id_res  check
0   paris      12  False
1   paris      12  False
2  nantes      14  False
3  berlin      28   True
4  berlin       8  False
5  berlin       4  False
6   tokyo      89  False
```

Details:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, m1.rename('m1'), m2.rename('m2')])
      col  id_res  check     m1     m2
0   paris      12  False   True  False
1   paris      12  False   True  False
2  nantes      14  False  False   True
3  berlin      28   True   True   True  # <-  group to check
4  berlin       8  False   True   True  # <-     because 
5  berlin       4  False   True   True  # <- m1 and m2 are True
6   tokyo      89  False  False   True
```

Comment: *In fine* you have 3 conditions, so I find it more explicit to use 3 masks ;)

Comment: Maybe but you have to evaluate the group twice for m2 and m3. I had almost the same solution at start but I think it's more obvious to check 1 condition per column then, in a second time, check the highest value of the group. Question of perspective :)

Comment: And `transform` is not so obvious! Explain the broadcast :)